# Multiple scrollbar inside iframe asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

I have an application built based on Admin LTE template. The application is basically an asp.net classic application. There is a master page and I have a iframe embedd in the master page.

Based on the menu selected by the user I am loading the iframe content which will be another asp.net webpage. The child asp.net web page (iframe content page) has another iframe which is been dynamically loaded with another content.

Totally I have 2 iframes which loads contents. The layout will be as shown in below image

[image]

My issue is the height of the iframe is being fixed in the code and when the loaded content is more than the iframe height I am getting a scroll bar apart from the main window scroll bar.

In order to avoid this,  I added the iframe resizer from the [link](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)

And also added few javascript as shown below

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
         obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';               
       }
```

and on page load server side method i am calling the javascript using

```
letterframe.Attributes.Add("onload", "resizeIframe(this);");
```

as the iframe is set to runat = "server"

This code works fine however when i have nested iframe views it didnt worked.

hence I modified the javascript as

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
         obj.style.height = (obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + parent.document.body.scrollHeight) + 'px'; 
       }
```

This code has removed the scrollbar from the nested iframe however i am getting a blank space after my content as the height has been determined by adding the parent page height and the iframe content scroll height.

Can anyone let me know how to fit the height so that i can avoid scrollbars in the iframe?

Comment: I think this is a css issue isn't it? Try defining the max-height of the parent to 100%, this should force the iframe to adjust onload. *Edit 1*, I'm not sure if I understood the question correct, but the mentioned solution should remove the page scrollbar and leave you with the iframe scrollbar if that works for you. Otherwise I'd suggest it the other way around where you declare no max height, in this case the parent container should grow with its child components, in this case the iframe

Comment: @TobiasWürth. The javascript will change the height of the iframe so that the iframe gets resized dynamically based on the content page height so that there wont be a scroll bar inside iframe. Also the parent container has to grow with its child components. If not i will get a scrollbar along with the parent scrollbar.

Comment: If you only want to have a scrollbar on the main page but not the iframe, do not specify the height of the iframe explicitly. This way it should try to grow in height as far as it needs to be. The result should be a scrollable main page with an iframe without a scrollbar

Comment: @TobiasWürth I tried that but it didnt worked. Normally iframe will not adjust its height automatically based on the content window.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of the loaded css of the two components once rendered? Maybe some default value is enforcing this behavior